# Unrar works really slow compared to Winrar?

Tags: 12.10, compression

Is there a particular reason why Unrar operations are so slow comparing to Winrar on Windows. I managed to extract a file faster in Virtualbox (Windows 7 guest with Winrar).

Comment: What filesystem does the partion you extract from/to have?

Comment: @stonedsquirrel Ubuntu has ext4, and Windows (virtualized ) has NTFS

Comment: Which RAR implementation are you using? There's the package `unrar-free` and `unrar` (non-free). My best guess is that the implementation in Linux isn't multi-threaded.